# Compose multiplatform app with multiple Activities. Is it possible?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

I'm an Android developer, and I'm trying to write a Compose Multiplatform Mobile application that will work on both Android and iOS. I have created a new multiplatform project with Android Studio and started writing some shared `@Composable`s.

I created a `Button` and in `onClick` function I want to start another activity and potentially pass some arguments. In Android we call `startActivity()` with `Intent` object. What should I do in Kotlin/Native for iOS?

I've tried to create `expect` class with `@Composable` function as parameter:

```
expect class CustomActivity(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {}
```

Now, in the Android part, I can create `actual` class:

```
actual class CustomActivity actual constructor(private val content: @Composable () -> Unit) : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            content()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm stuck in the iOS part. I tried to create another `actual` class, but I do not know what to put there. Should it be in Kotlin or Swift?

Comment: if you want to manage navigation from shared code, I would suggest using some KMP navigation library, such as [Decompose](https://github.com/arkivanov/Decompose). Using it you can then manage displaying content with platform methods, like activity on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation can get tricky if you want multiple separate "screens" (if that's what you mean by Activity) where sometimes you just want "separation of concerns" between screens. You would achieve this behavior on Android by simply declaring multiple activities in your manifest and then move from an activity to another using `Intents`. I believe this part is already clear.

On iOS, we do not have a direct equivalent of `Activity`, but we do have `ViewControllers` which can be obtained via `ComposeUIViewController`(I believe you're already familiar with the process of adding these ViewControllers to your SwiftUI code by using UIViewControllerRepresentable).

You can replace `ViewControllers` back and forth as much as you like, based on some state boolean or something. The only caveat is that you have to do this via SwiftUI code, not Kotlin Native code. Here's an example to a simple `ViewController` navigation:

```swift
@State var screen: String = "main"


//iOSApp SwiftUI 

switch screen {
case "main":
    // Code for the main screen
    break
case "stuff":
    // Code for the stuff screen
    break
case "options":
    // Code for the options screen
    break
default:
    // Code to handle other cases
    break
}
```

Then, all you need to is create some kind of "bridge" between your SwiftUI code and Kotlin Native in order to control the "screen" state variable (For example, using some lambdas or protocol callback).

Now let's take it up a notch, you want to produce some kind of animation navigation flow the same way Android has when you call `startActivity` ? In iOS, you can create such flow using `NavigationView`. You can use a NavigationView in your `iOSApp` `@main` under your WindowGroup so it manages all the screens, here's how:

```swift
//iOSApp
@State var secondaryScreen = false //some state to control navigation
var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                ZStack {
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: SecondaryScreen().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                            .onAppear {
                                UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
                            }
                            .onDisappear {
                                UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
                            },
                        isActive: $secondaryScreen
                    ) {}
                    if (!secondaryScreen) {
                        MainScreen(somelambda: { self.secondaryScreen = true })

                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Notice how I passed `somelambda` to my `MainScreen` UIViewControllerRepresentable ? Which will be passed to the `ComposeUIViewRepresentable`, which will be passed to the Compose code, which will be passed to a button's `onClick`, which will execute the navigation. It's a pretty long route indeed, but I could've done it in a much simpler way, this was just one of them.

When you have more screens, create more NavigationLinks, and control the state using an Int or Stirng rather than a boolean. The hardest part about all of this is how you can control your state variables from Kotlin Native code, which as I said before can be done by passing around parameters or using interface/protocol callbacks. There isn't really just one way to do it.

Comment: But doesn't this kind of defeat the purpose of Compose Multiplatform? It should be able to do this on its own, otherwise you might start to get a huge mess.

Comment: @SimaoGomesViana Indeed, multiple-activity architecture is strongly discouraged nowadays, especially with the rise of Compose multiplatform. It makes the matters all the more complicated without any catch